# Using bracket notation on redux reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a form that should update my store for every change done in the store. To not have to make 20-30 different actions for each property/field, i though creating one single action containing property-name and value would be a good approach. So the action looks like this:

```
export function(property, value){
    return{
        type: UPDATE_MODEL,
        property: property,
        value: value
    }
}
```

When passing that into my reducer, i tried using the bracket notation.

```
case UPDATE_MODEL: {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {[action.property]: action.value});
}
```

When doing this:

```
dispatch(myAction("Type", {Id: 1}));
```

My reducer will set the Type property to an array instead of just setting the property Type to the incoming object. Is there a way to rig this properly?

I tried to use _cloneDeep from lodash on the current state object i wanted to change, then used the bracket notation on that, and then returning object.assign with that new object, that actually works, it just feels very wrong though.

Comment: For complex form, consider using redux-form

Comment: Its not very complex, and i prefer to do it as pure and lightweight as possible to minimize dependencies, and keep control. I looked at redux-forms, but it is way too much for the stuff im doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function updateModel(state, action) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.property]: action.value
  })
}

function updateModelAction(property, value) {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_MODEL',
    property,
    value
  }
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_MODEL':
      return updateModel(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

console.log(reducer({}, updateModelAction('foo', { bar: 'baz' })))
```

Comment: that code is exactly like my own, the only change you did was extracting the object.assign to a new function. But from what i can see when running your snippet, is that it actually returns what i expect. What is different?

Comment: I noticed that after I posted this answer haha. What does your `myAction` function look like?

Comment: And what is the result you get? Something is wrong with your code somewhere :]

Comment: i was getting an array for everything i piped trough that reducer (on that action). I need to do some more research i guess. The only thing i can see different is that im using the dispatcher, but that shouldnt really mean anything

Comment: Using `dispatch` doesn't do anything different though, it just passes that plain object to your reducer. You should create a fiddle with your code so we can see what's wrong! You might find an error while you do it.

Comment: i did this to an object lying a level deeper than the root, i must have messed up something awful. I got it working now, doing the same as you do. I even tried to reproduce my issue, but i really cant. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! No worries.